# Getting invalid date issue while comparing dates in XSLT code

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a requirement wherein I have to validate couple of scenarios: the offer start date should fall before offer end date and the offer start date account should fall after account start date. If any of the scenario is not met error should be thrown.

Offer start date and offer end date values will appear in space separated formats in  xml tag and  xml tags respectively.

Below is the sample xml code:

```
<Accounts>
    <Account>
        <AccountStartDate>2020-12-01<AccountStartDate>
        <offerStartDate>2020-10-02 2020-11-02</offerStartDate>
        <offerEndDate>2019-10-02 2019-11-02</offerEndDate>
    </Account>
</Accounts>
```

Below is the sample xslt code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Accounts/Account">
    <xsl:variable name="offerSDate" select="offerStartDate"/>
    <xsl:variable name="offerEDate" select="offerEndDate"/>
                
    <xsl:if test="$offerSDate &gt; xs:date(AccountStartDate)">
        <Error>
            <xsl:text>Error: Invalid offer Date &#xA;</xsl:text>
        </Error>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$offerSDate &gt; $offerEDate">
        <Error>
            <xsl:text>Error: Invalid offer Date &#xA;</xsl:text>
        </Error>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

After execution of the xslt code, I am getting the invalid date "2020-10-02 2020-11-02""issue.

Comment: `<offerStartDate>2020-10-02 2020-11-02</offerStartDate>`  TWO dates here?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Two offer start dates are present in the same xml tag but they are separated by space. Multiple offer start dates will appear as space separated and same is the case with offer end dates.

Comment: But `2020-10-02 2020-11-02` is not a date, that is what the error message says! Maybe you should take a [substring](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_substring.html) of it?

Comment: But if I will take a substring of the offerstartdate and offerenddate, then how can I compare each offerstartend with each offerenddate. Also then how can I compare each offerstartdate with AccountStartDate. Basically, as I want to compare each offerstartdate with each offerenddate, then is there a way I can first create some sort of list and then compare them in XSLT.

Comment: You are better off, when you convert your current xml, to an xml which only contains `date`s, and not `text` like it is currently.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a separate comparison for each date in `offerStartDate`, then you could do (in XSLT 2.0) either:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="Account">
        <xsl:if test="some $offerStartDate in tokenize(offerStartDate, ' ') satisfies xs:date($offerStartDate) gt xs:date(AccountStartDate)">
            <Error>error message</Error>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

or (depending on what meaning your test should have):

```
    <xsl:for-each select="Account">
        <xsl:if test="every $offerStartDate in tokenize(offerStartDate, ' ') satisfies xs:date($offerStartDate) gt xs:date(AccountStartDate)">
            <Error>error message</Error>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably the easiest way to do it with only XSLT is to convert your XML from:

```
<Accounts>
    <Account>
        <AccountStartDate>2020-12-01</AccountStartDate>
        <offerStartDate>2020-10-02 2020-11-02</offerStartDate>
        <offerEndDate>2019-10-02 2019-11-02</offerEndDate>
    </Account>
</Accounts>
```

To something like:

```
<Accounts>
    <Account>
        <AccountStartDate>2020-12-01</AccountStartDate>
        <offer>
         <offerStartDate>2020-10-02</offerStartDate>
         <offerEndDate>2019-10-02</offerEndDate>
        </offer>
        <offer>
         <offerStartDate>2020-11-02</offerStartDate>
         <offerEndDate>2019-11-02</offerEndDate>
        </offer>
    </Account>
</Accounts>
```

Comment: The xml that I am currently receiving from the upstream system is not modifiable, I have to manage the output somehow with the same xml only. Is there a way in XSLT with which I can compare the space separated values in one tag with the space separated values in another tag?